# Generate all the variations of template using Jinja2

Tags: python, templates, jinja2

I am trying to implement some kind of utility, which generates all the variations (combinations) of some template. For example:

```
{% all_combinations %}
     {% one_of('Hello', 'Welcome') %}, {% one_of('Jack', 'Alex') %}!
{% endall_combinations %}
```

Should output the following:

```
Hello, Jack
Hello, Alex
Welcome, Jack
Welcome, Alex
```

I've choosen Jinja2 for this goal. Could you advice me how to implement this? or suggest me another solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this,

```
from jinja2 import Template
t = Template("{{ greeting }}, {{ someone }}")

greetings = ('Hello','Welcome')
someones = ('Jack', 'Alex')

for g in greetings:
   for s in someones:
     print(t.render(greeting=g, someone=s))
```